# How do I dedicate more of my machines resources to a specific task?

Tags: macos, time-machine, encryption, filevault, activity-monitor

I don't know how FileVault even got turned on in my 2012 MacBook Pro running MacOS Catalina.. But it's been trying to do its initial encryption for 4 days now, over the past 20 hours I have simply let it sit and run and it has only moved from 40%-43%.. I have stopped basically all background tasks and My Activity Monitor says the machine is running around 95% idle at this point.  Im curious what FileVault would be called in Activity Monitor so I can find that specific task and if there is a way for me to force the mac to dedicate more power to getting the task done so I can do a TimeMachine Backup and move on.

I was able to get everything I think I'll need to start over onto an external HD so at this point I might just reformat the drive and start over if I cant get it to finish this encryption today.

Comment: It needs to be awake & plugged into the mains for encryption to proceed. Is it?

Comment: 2012, you say -- Is this a mechanical hard drive, or an SSD? FileVault could be taking forever if there is a fault or failure on the storage device.